# what's the gap with this ad lookup code?

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

I'm using ETL to store AD users in a local SQL Server database.  The following AD lookup code populates the Guid, FirstName and LastName of all AD users who belong to a particular group:

```
var adPrincipalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domainName);
var group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(adPrincipalContext, groupName);
var members = group.GetMembers();
var groupUsers = new List<Tuple<Guid, string, string>>();

var enumerator = members.GetEnumerator();
while (enumerator.MoveNext())
{
    var user = enumerator.Current as UserPrincipal;
    groupUsers.Add(new Tuple <Guid, string, string>( 
        (Guid)user.Guid, user.GivenName, user.Surname));
}
```

The problem is that for about 1/2 of these users, the user guid that gets populated into the groupUsers list above is different than the guid returned by a direct AD query by user DisplayName like this:

```
    using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domainName))
    {
        // init vars
        var up = new UserPrincipal(context);
        var ps = new PrincipalSearcher(up);
        var allUsers = ps.FindAll().ToList();
        var user2 = allUsers.Where(x => 
            x.DisplayName == groupUser.Item3 + ", " + groupUser.Item2).FirstOrDefault();        
    }
```

Any idea what the problem might be?  I need to return my database representation of each user based on a db lookup of the AD user's Guid.

- Both code blocks consistently return the same guid for the same user within the respective code block
- About 1/2 of the user guids returned in the first code block match the user guids returned in the second code block
- About 1/2 of the user guids returned in the first code block *don't* match the user guids returned in the second code block

Any idea what might be causing this discrepancy?

Answer (score 0):

Display names don't have to be unique. You may have multiple accounts with the same display name.

For a quick test, you can modify your second block of code to throw an exception if it finds multiple accounts. If you get an exception, then you know that's the problem:

```
using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domainName))
{
    // init vars
    var up = new UserPrincipal(context);
    var ps = new PrincipalSearcher(up);
    var allUsers = ps.FindAll().ToList();
    var users = allUsers.Where(x => 
        x.DisplayName == groupUser.Item3 + ", " + groupUser.Item2).ToList();

    if (users.Count > 1) {
        throw new Exception("More than one account found for: " + groupUser.Item3 + ", " + groupUser.Item2)
    }

    var user2 = users.FirstOrDefault();
}
```